# Kubernetes Ingress Controller with multiple paths - only forwards to correct service half the time?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, nginx-ingress, kong, kong-ingress, ingress-controller

I am currently running Kong via Helm inside of a Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) cluster. I have created the following Kubernetes Ingress Controller which forwards traffic to two services based on paths.

I noticed a very strange behaviour that the ingress controller works only half the time i.e. when accessing `/api/foo`, half the time I would be forwarded to `bar-service` and the other half of the time I would be forwarded to the correct `foo-service`, and vice versa.

Have I configured my Ingress correctly? Thank you!

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: kong-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "true"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "kong"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /api/foo
        backend:
          serviceName: foo-service
          servicePort: 8080
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: bar-service
          servicePort: 8080
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved! It turns out both `foo-service`, and `bar-service` share the same selector, and `matchLabels` with their respective deployments. And therefore half the time `foo-service` is served by `foo-deployment` and the other half is served by `bar-deployment`.